# Changing 2D table (obtained by pd.read_excel) into DataFrame with datetime index

Tags: pandas

How can I change the following 2D table (obtained by pd.read_excel) to pandas DataFrame with datetime index?  In other words,

**From** (data_xlsx): obtained by: data_xlsx = pd.read_excel(' ...')

[image]

**To:**

1948-01-01  3.4
1948-02-01  3.8
1948-03-01  4.0
. . .
1952-11-01  2.8
1952-12-01  2.7

Comment: from where the month and date came?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] with code/text that can be copied to reproduce your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
df = df.melt('Year', value_name='val')
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df['Year'].astype(str) + df['variable'], format='%Y%b')
df = df.sort_index()[['val']]
```

**Explanation**:

1. First reshape by [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html)
2. Create `DatetimeIndex` by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) with custom format, check http://strftime.org/.
3. Last [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) and select only `val` column

Alternative solution:

```
df = df.set_index('Year').stack()
df.index = (pd.to_datetime(df.index.get_level_values(0).astype(str) + 
                          df.index.get_level_values(1), format='%Y%b'))
df = df.to_frame('val')
```

**Explanation**:

1. Create index from `Year` column by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html)
2. Reshape by [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for `MultiIndex`
3. Create `DatetimeIndex` by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) and select levels by [`get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html)
4. Last if necessary create one column `DataFrame` by [`Series.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_frame.html)

**Sample**:

```
np.random.seed(1213)

c = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr','May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(5,12)), columns=c)
df.insert(0, 'Year', np.arange(1948, 1953))
print (df)
   Year  Jan  Feb  Mar  Apr  May  Jun  Jul  Aug  Sep  Oct  Nov  Dec
0  1948    0    5    4    8    0    4    6    3    3    0    1    7
1  1949    9    5    2    9    3    1    7    6    3    8    9    2
2  1950    9    5    2    1    6    8    7    7    6    6    5    7
3  1951    1    9    9    3    1    4    0    1    5    1    1    4
4  1952    3    7    1    1    7    3    7    6    8    8    6    1
```

---

```
df = df.set_index('Year').stack()
df.index = (pd.to_datetime(df.index.get_level_values(0).astype(str) +
                           df.index.get_level_values(1), format='%Y%b'))
df = df.to_frame('val')
print (df.head(10))
            val
1948-01-01    0
1948-02-01    5
1948-03-01    4
1948-04-01    8
1948-05-01    0
1948-06-01    4
1948-07-01    6
1948-08-01    3
1948-09-01    3
1948-10-01    0
```

Comment: @east - You are welcome! You can upvote too - click to small triangle above `0` above accepting mark. Thanks.